# Why is my query result not complete?

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

I have made an application with php and a report with TCPDF, is no problem and the select query runs properly. But if I look at the data very carefully, I find the first data is missing.

Simple example query:

```
 SELECT * FROM tb_expedition
```

If I run this query on MySQL, all of the data will appear. If the query is run from my php program, the result is still not complete. If the total data is 20 rows, in php appear only 19 rows, and the first data is missing.

This is my code:

```
<?php

require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
 include "koneksi.php";//conection file

  $period=$_GET[PERIOD];

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_exp_expor where period = ' $period'";

   $hasil = mysql_query($sql);
   $data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);

   $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

   // set font
      $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 11);

// landscape
   $pdf->addPage( 'L', 'LETTER' );

   $html = '
<table border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="4">
    <tr><td colspan="9" align="center"><h2>Form Pantauan Expedisi Export</h2></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="center"><b>Tanggal</b></th>
        <th align="center"><b>Nama Expedisi</b></th>
        <th align="center"><b>Nama Distributor</b></th>
        <th align="center"><b>Kota Tujuan</b></th>
        <th align="center"><b>No Faktur</b></th>
        <th align="center"><b>Kondisi Armada Pengiriman</b></th>
        <th align="center"><b>Ketepatan Jumlah</b></th>
        <th align="center"><b>Ketepatan Waktu Kirim</b></th>
        <th align="center"><b>Keterangan</b></th>
    </tr></table>';
     $no=0;
   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
   {

     $html .= '<table border="1"><tr><td align="center">'.$data['tgl'].'</td>
                   <td align="center">'.$data['nama_exp_expor'].'</td>
                   <td align="center">'.$data['nama_distributor'].'</td>
                   <td align="center">'.$data['kota_tujuan'].'</td>
                   <td align="center">'.$data['no_faktur'].'</td>
                   <td align="center">'.$data['kon_armada'].'</td>
                   <td align="center">'.$data['ketepatan_jml'].'</td>
                   <td align="center">'.$data['ketepatan_wkt_kirim'].'</td> 
                   <td align="center">'.$data['ket'].'</td>  
                   </tr></table> ';

    $no++;             
    }

   $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');



   $pdf->Output('Daftar_Expedisi_Local', 'I');

?>
```

Comment: Problem is quite likely to be in your PHP code receiving the data. Show us that.

Comment: the mysql statement is fine. Show us the rest of code.

Comment: you may be doing mysql_fetch_array one extra time somewhere...

Comment: $data = mysql_fetch_array($sql); <- what's this for?

Comment: @Onheiron its just for check,  I Will delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are some of your lines, with some of the echos removed

```
 $query = mysql_query($sql);
 $data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

THat second line is really strange: you do an extra fetch_array, but with the sql-string as argument? That's not really useful, doens't that give an error?

You should clean up some of this code, for instance, don't perform extra "fetch_array"'s you don't need. If it doesn't function after that, remove all unneccesaire lines (echoes, colors, etc) that you do not need for debugging. You can more quickly find out what's going on that way :)

While you're at it, you should really look at moving from the `mysql_` functions. Read this nice big read warning in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

> Suggested alternatives
>
> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL
>   extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and
>   related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function
>   include:
>
> mysqli_fetch_array()
>   PDOStatement::fetch()

Now try this please. THIS Is what you should have done in the first place as a "small as possible" example.

```
<?php
  include "koneksi.php";//conection file
  $period=$_GET[PERIOD];  
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_exp_expor where period = ' $period'";
  var_dump($sql);//you can check this query in your database manually

  $hasil = mysql_query($sql);       
  //NO FETCH ARRAY HERE!

   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){
        var_dump($data);
    }

?>
```

Please notice the:

1. REMOVAL of the extra fetch array.
2. REMOVAL of all the HTML and PDF stuff for debugging
3. SMALL, as much as possible self-contained code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check it again  I already delete the extra fetch array, but it still same, actually data missing in tcpdf. But the  query is still simple like that.

Comment: I Try to read all your advice, and try it to my script, but it still wrong, My PHP result still not complate and missing the first row. I'm confuses about that. Anyone help me?

Comment: As far as tryin everything, I specifically adviced you to remove all things that you don't need for testing your problem, e.g. your echoes. Please do so, and show that code here. Write a script that can do only 1 query, performs that, and then echos only the id's (or something) of the result. As small and self-contained as possible. THen show that code here, with the result. Good change is you will find the bug during this process, but if not, that would be the thing to post here. The html, colors etc are not important here.

Comment: I Have been change, please recheck my code. Because the code is still missing the first row in database.

Comment: You are still doing an extra `mysql_fetch_array($hasil);`. you shouldn't

Comment: PLease take a look at my code, and try to learn from it how to ask a better question. Next time, when you do ask a question this way, you will probably find the answer during the process :)

Comment: Thanks My Friend. It's work ==), I dont think have double mysql_fetch_array can missing 1 row result. Thanks A lot for your Advice.   Thanks..

Comment: Well, it means you fetch a row, ignore it, and then start fetching the rest of the rows :)